# UITableView hide first cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I am trying to recreate the common pull down to refresh user interface that you see in many apps these days. The first cell is the one which is hidden and has the refresh loading on it, how to I get my table view to start at index row 1 rather then 0 so my refresh cell is hidden?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Sam